# What program is missing?

Tags: windows, mt

I got the error below while running a pre-written cmd file on Windows.

```
'mt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The use case is:

```
mt -manifest <... something else....>
```

It's obvious that it needs some `mt`, but I can't figure what `mt` really is, so I could install the thing.

Could anyone tell me what this is or where to get it?

Thanks

Comment: You need to show us the contents of the .cmd file…

Comment: `mt` could literally be anything. What is this prewritten `.cmd` file supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the context of a batch file, it's probably a backup script, so you're probably looking for this:

http://www.holistech.co.uk/sw/mt/mt.html

Or if it's a script from a dev project, it probably refers to this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375649(v=vs.85).aspx

Again, what does the script *do*?

Comment: no, but there're many answers that match `mt`. Just don't feeling getting the wrong one

Comment: The use case is `mt -manifest....`

Comment: Then it's almost certainly the second option I posted - which means you need to either install the entire Windows SDK, or at least that portion of it

Comment: The script is for packaging software

Comment: Is it possible to get the Mt.exe ONLY? (w/o getting the entire sdkset up? My disk space is VERY limited)

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I don't know; I'm not a Windows/.NET developer, sorry.